# Creating multiple custom summaries on the same grid (and calculating a summary that only sums specific numbers)

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, summary

I am trying to create another custom summary that works on the same grid. I already have the following which calculates a percentage from two other columns.

I am now trying to add another custom summary that sums the values of the column called TestErrors. The cells in this coulmn only have 3 different values: 0, 1 and 128. I want to do a sum of all the values that are NOT 128 (if 4 cells contained 0, 1, 1 and 128 the sum would be 2).

How do I create two different custom summaries on the same grid and how do I calculate the summary where it discounts 128?

Edit: Using nempo's answer below I got the following, but it is not working properly. No value shows.

XAML:

```
<dxg:GridControl.GroupSummary>
                                                <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="TestAmount" SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="Number of tests: {0}"/>
                                                <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="TestErrors" SummaryType="Custom" DisplayFormat="Number of errors: {0}" Tag="custsumError"/>
                                                <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="TestErrorRate" SummaryType="Custom" DisplayFormat="Error rate: {0:P4}" Tag="custsumRate"/>
                                            </dxg:GridControl.GroupSummary>
```

C#:

```
private void dxgErrorGrid_CustomSummary(object sender, DevExpress.Data.CustomSummaryEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.IsTotalSummary)
                return;

            switch (e.SummaryProcess)
            {
                case CustomSummaryProcess.Start:

                    sumErrors = 0;
                    sumTests = 0;
                    sumTestErrors = 0;

                    break;

                case CustomSummaryProcess.Calculate:

                    var testError = Convert.ToInt32(((clsErrorData)e.Row).TestErrors);

                    sumTests += ((clsErrorData)e.Row).TestAmount;
                    sumErrors += testError;
                    sumTestErrors += testError != 128 ? testError : 0;

                    break;

                case CustomSummaryProcess.Finalize:

                    var summary = e.Item as GridSummaryItem;

                    if (summary == null || summary.Tag == null)
                        return;

                    switch (summary.Tag.ToString())
                    {
                        case "custsumError":
                            e.TotalValue = sumTestErrors;
                            break;

                        case "custsumRate":
                            e.TotalValue = (decimal)sumErrors / sumTests;
                            break;
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create two different custom summaries you can use XAML or `GridControl.GroupSummary.Add` method.
Example for XAML:

```xml
<dxg:GridControl.GroupSummary>
    <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="YourFieldName" SummaryType="Custom" Tag="Custom0"/>
    <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="YourFieldName" SummaryType="Custom" Tag="Custom1"/>
</dxg:GridControl.GroupSummary>
```

Example for c#:

```
dxgErrorGrid.GroupSummary.Add(SummaryItemType.Custom, "YourFieldName").Tag = "Custom0";
dxgErrorGrid.GroupSummary.Add(SummaryItemType.Custom, "YourFieldName").Tag = "Custom1";
```

In `GridControl.CustomSummary` event you can use [`SummaryItemBase.Tag`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridSummaryItemBase_Tagtopic) property to easily identify which summary item is currently processed.
Here is example:

```
private int sumErrors;
private int sumTests;
private int sumTestErrors;

private void dxgErrorGrid_CustomSummary(object sender, CustomSummaryEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsGroupSummary)
        return;

    switch (e.SummaryProcess)
    {
        case CustomSummaryProcess.Start:

            sumErrors = 0;
            sumTests = 0;
            sumTestErrors = 0;

            break;

        case CustomSummaryProcess.Calculate:

            var testError = Convert.ToInt32(((clsErrorData)e.Row).TestErrors);

            sumTests += ((clsErrorData)e.Row).TestAmount;
            sumErrors += testError;
            sumTestErrors += testError != 128 ? testError : 0;

            break;

        case CustomSummaryProcess.Finalize:

            var summary = e.Item as GridSummaryItem;

            if (summary == null || summary.Tag == null)
                return;

            switch (summary.Tag.ToString())
            {
                case "Custom0":
                    e.TotalValue = (decimal)sumErrors / sumTests;
                    break;
                case "Custom1":
                    e.TotalValue = sumTestErrors;
                    break;
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer nempo, but it seems to not be working as it should. I have edited my initial post with what I did. Can you see what's wrong (it's almost just copy paste of your post)? The summaries at each row does not show any numbers just the "Number of errors:"

Comment: @St0ffer My example is about `TotalSummary`, but you are using `GroupSummary`. Just change `if (!e.IsTotalSummary)` to `if (!e.IsGroupSummary)`.

Comment: Doh, completely missed that. Thanks again, it's working now :)